# php Opening file using file_get_contents or curl through windows auth

Tags: php, curl

Ive got a website where i want to open a file from another server. this server is connected using a network drive.

The file uses Windows authentication. Because of this, using

`echo file_get_contents('\\\**.**.local/data/user/*/*.xlsx');`

results in

```
file_get_contents(\\*.*.local/data/user/*/*.xlsx) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

I found a similar problem here: 
[How to use file_get_contents() to retrieve a file behind Windows NT Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121902/how-to-use-file-get-contents-to-retrieve-a-file-behind-windows-nt-auth)

But I cant get it to work. Using this:

```
getUrl('\\\*.*.local/data/user/*/*.xlsx','username','password');
```

Always results in :

```
Could not resolve host: \\*.*.local
```

Using

```
getUrl('file://*.*.local/data/user/*/*.xlsx','username','password');
```

gives me

> Couldn't open file
>   /data/user/*/*.xlsx

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can both use:

```
getUrl('file:////*.*.local/data/user/*/*.xlsx','username','password');
```

or

```
getUrl('file://\\*.*.local\data\user\*\*.xlsx','username','password');
```

Comment: `getUrl('file:////*.*.local/data/user/*/*.xlsx','username','password');`

gives me :

 `Couldn't open file //*.*.local/data/user/*/*.xlsx`
`getUrl('file://\\*.*.local\data\user\*\*.xlsx','username','password');`

gives me 

    `Couldn't open file /data/user/*/*.xlsx`

Comment: Try the url in a file-explorer first

Comment: I am not 100% sure its the path that creates the problem. It also could be the username/password. I tried "username" abd "domain\username" but both didnt work.